A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `err`
A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: err. Value: [Error: redux-persist: persist timed out for persist key "rootApp"]
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {"err": [Error: redux-persist: persist timed out for persist key "rootApp"], "key": "rootApp", "payload": undefined, "type": "persist/REHYDRATE"}
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants)
(To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)
